# How do you select an option when the page opens?

Tags: jquery, select

I'm just not getting this for some reason. I've tried various ways of using quotes, etc, but nothing works so far.

The URL I'm passing to the page is:

http://dev.bizzocall.com/indx-signup.php?plan='#Flexi'
I've also tried

```
http://dev.bizzocall.com/indx-signup.php?plan=#Flexi
http://dev.bizzocall.com/indx-signup.php?plan=Flexi
http://dev.bizzocall.com/indx-signup.php?plan='Flexi'
```

(and writing the switch statement differently to accomodate the differences....

What am I missing?

```
(function($) {
    $.QueryString = (function(a) {
        if (a == "") return {};
        var b = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        {
            var p=a[i].split('=');
            if (p.length != 2) continue;
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        return b;
    })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {

    $myplan = $.QueryString["plan"];     
      switch ($myplan) {
              case "#Flexi": 
                  $aSel="#Flexi";
                  break;
              case "#Grow": 
                  $aSel="#Grow";
                  break;
              case "#Excel": 
                    $aSel="#Excel";
                    break;
              case "#Max": 
                  $aSel="#Max";
                  break;
          }
      ($aSel).addAttr('selected', true)
          .siblings('option')
       .removeAttr('selected');

});
```

Comment: You might be better off doing this server side by printing `selected="selected"` in the option you want selected. What language are you using?

Comment: JamWaffles -- This is the approach I'm attempting now.  I'm trying to write the entire select box with php.  Its not going well, so far. I think I'll try your idea.  A lot less escaping goin' on... But, I have successfully passed the value from the action page to the page with the select box, so I got that going for me....

Comment: I went back to basics.  Passed the value to the page in an URL query.  I just wrote out the whole select box with PHP, with the different versions in a switch statement. It's long, but understandable and simple. Got it working! Thanks for the comments, guys!

Comment: JamWaffles -- if you'll submit an answer here instead of a comment, I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an option to be set when the page loads, it's better to do it serverside; if the user has JS disabled, the option won't be set. You said you're using PHP in a comment, so I'll give an example using that.

For these kinds of situations, I like to use an array of options to print out the `<select>` box, a bit like this:

```
$options = array('value' => 'Text', '1' => 'Choice 1', 'foo' => 'Choice foo');
$selectedOption = 'foo';    // What we want to be selected (value)

echo '<select name="whatever">';

// Loop through options
foreach($options as $value => $text) {
    // If this is the selected value, add the selected attribute
    if($value == $selectedOption) {
        echo '<option selected="selected" value="' . $value . '">' . $text . '</option>';
    else {
        echo '<optoin value="' . $value . '">' . $text . '</option>';
    }
}

echo '</select>';    // Close select tag
```

The code above loops through an array of values. When it finds a key in the array that matches `$selectedOption` it gives that `<option>` the `selected="selected"` attribute. This method saves having to type out a huge load of HTML with bits of PHP everywhere. I usually put this code in a function and pass it an associative array and a selected option, but it's entirely up to you.

Comment: Yep.  Much better than the way I've done it.  But, if it ain't broke don't fix it, that's my motto.  I'll def. try this next time.

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE 2/11 6:51P

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object $aSel has no method 'addAttr'
```

Because $aSel = somthing like "#IDName" and not an actual jQuery object. To be a jQuery object it needs to be something more like `$("EleIDNameofExistingEle")` or `$("<option />").attr({ id: 'EleIDName' });`

> OLD

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $aSel is not defined
```

Try establishing $aSel as a variable first.

Also, Codeigniter for PHP works great with jQuery and makes things like passing variable data to a page as easy as `$this->load->view('somePage', array( $data1=>'aString', $data2=>json_encode(array( 'item1'=>'blah', 'item2'=>'blaj' )));` and then recall on the page as simple as `var aString = <?= $data1; ?>, aObj = <?= $data2; ?>;`

And CI now has a great new library for using jQuery directly on the page from server side

Comment: I changed back to passing straight text, such as ?plan=Flexi  and declared the variable like this  <<var $aSel = '#Free';
Now I get an "Uncaught TypeError, Object $aSel has no method 'addAttr'.  So for some reason the addAttr handler is not picking up the parameter as an html id.  Hmmm

Comment: Also, might i suggest, on your inputs, leave the base value blank and move your current values to an attr named `placeholder`.  While it's not recognized in some older browsers, there are several good jQuery plugins that will convert your placeholder attr to a similar javascript function specifically for older browsers

Comment: I haven't used Codeigniter.  Unfortunately, I'm using Dreamweaver, which has been a trail of tears when I got through with the layout and general navigation and got into making the pages do something with php and mysql. But, I'm pretty far down the path now. Reminds me of an old joke:  "hey Doc.  My wife thinks she's a chicken.  Is this bad?  Doc says 'Dude, bring her in, I'll fix it.  Dude says, no no I don't want to fix it.  I need the eggs.